# Android Gallary

Tags: android, zooming, gallery, imageview, gesture

I am trying to implement a Image Gallery with zoom in and zoom out facilities on every images.

for this i have extended ImageView and added zoom in zoom out mechanism with it, then in the Adapter class i return my own ImageView. But unfortunately it is not working with current Gallery widget.

my image view skeleton is like this

```
public class myImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener{}
```

My adapter class code is also simple i just use my ImageView instead of original one. Zoom in Zoom out in my ImageView works fine without gallery but not with gallery.

Any, advice?

Comment: Have you figured out any solution? @minhazrafichowdhury